# Display digits in Western Arabic

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding

I want to display digits in **Western Arabic** like "0123456789" regardless of my windows local. I have seen many methods that convert to **Eastern** Arabic like "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"

```
const UInt16 sh = 0x0660 - 0x0030;
string ConvertToEasternArabic(string value)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    String lst = value.ToString();
    foreach (char x in lst)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(x))
        {
            UInt16 c = Convert.ToUInt16(x);
            c += sh;
            s.Append(Convert.ToChar(c));
        }
        else
            s.Append(x);
    }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

But I want the opposite

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. How are you treating the numbers? How are you displaying them? What comes out, what do you want to come out? How does that code relate to the problem?

Comment: Ok I have a web application that may be working on machines that display numbers like "0123456789" or "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩" so i want to keep some specific controls to display numbers as "0123456789" even on those machine that display numbers like "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. `NumberFormatInfo` class has `NativeDigits` property. But, [MSDN says that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits.aspx):

> Only the Basic Latin digits 0 (U+0030) through 9 (U+0039) are used when formatting or parsing numeric values or date and time values

It means that regardless of windows local `string.Format()` and `int.ToString()` digits 0-9 are used to produce output string.

Comment: I have just checked it. Switched to ar-SA and `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(15))` still outputs `15`

Comment: Also you can always use InvariantCulture explicitly for formatting numbers

Comment: You need also to specify numbers format from Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional settings > Numbers Tab > set Standard digits to ""٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩" and set Use native digits to "National" you will see that all numbers will be like ""٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"

Comment: Yeah, I did it. And still it was printing 15. Does it work different way on your computer?

Comment: Please try it in windows application or web application

Comment: Why don't try yourself? :)